# array reordering based on key in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to re-arrange the following array where the alphabetic key should come first and then numerical keys.
Actually array is as follows.

```
Array
(
[1] => completed
[2] => completed
[3] => completed
[4] => completed
[5] => 
[user_name] => ABCD
)
```

and the output should looks as

```
 Array
(
[user_name] => ABCD
[1] => completed
[2] => completed
[3] => completed
[4] => completed
[5] => 
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wondering "why" here... You can address any element of an array by name via the associative array key, or by position via the numeric key.  I don't know of any good design pattern that would need to rearrange the array.  Maybe if you can tell us a little more about this, we could offer a better suggestion.

Comment: [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) is the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom sort like:

```
uksort($a, function($a, $b){

    if ( (is_numeric($a) && ! is_numeric($b)) ) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (!is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return $a > $b ? 1 : ($a == $b ? 0 : -1);

});
```

Comment: Second return statement should be -1, not 0

Comment: There is no need to write a uksort() algorithm.  The built-in PHP functions do exactly what the author needs.  Array keys are not subject to strict comparison.  Try the example and see.

Comment: The second return statement appears to be correct as written, according to my tests.

Comment: Second statement is right... if the first element is alpha and the second is numeric, I want to keep them as they are.

Comment: @RayPaseur your comment is almost correct. Except it doesn't stand when the array contains the key `0`. To make it worse, PHP changed the algorithm used by `ksort()` in PHP 7. Take a look here: https://3v4l.org/qRBMV

Comment: @GustavoJantsch `0` means "equal". The second return should be `-1` for "less than".

Comment: @axiac it makes no difference in my tests to say that they are equal or "less than", but ok, makes more sense.

Comment: We're not talking about sense here, we're talking about the [specifications](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php). The comparison function must return `-1` when the first value is "less than" (i.e. should be placed before) the second value it receives as argument. You said in a comment above: *"if the first element is alpha and the second is numeric, I want to keep them as they are"*. This statement translates in code to `return -1;`.

Comment: thanks for the discussion. i will look in to it. 
ksort($array,SORT_NUMERIC );  this will also solve the problem right?

Comment: @ChiruAdi, ksort with SORT_NUMERIC seems to fail if you have a index 0,  as far as I tested.

Comment: @GustavoJantsch i don't think it will fail. it will works fine. 0 it considers as numeric , after applying ksort numeric the order of array will be as  user_name,0,1,2,3,4,5 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The function you need is [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php). It sorts the array by keys, maintaining the key-value associations and allows you to write the sorting rules.

It could be like this:

```
$data = [
    1 => 'completed',
    2 => 'Completed',
    3 => 'completed',
    4 => 'completed',
    5 => NULL,
    'user_name' => 'KABCD',
];

uksort(
    $data,
    function ($a, $b) {
        if (is_string($a)) {
            return is_string($b) ? strcmp($a, $b) : -1;
        } else {
            return is_string($b) ? +1 : ($a - $b);
        }
    }
);
```

The callback function always returns "string < integer" when the types of the passed keys differ and it uses the appropriate comparison method when they are the same.

In PHP 7 the function can be written using the new [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
    function ($a, $b) {
        if (is_string($a)) {
            return is_string($b) ? ($a <=> $b) : -1;
        } else {
            return is_string($b) ? +1 : ($a <=> $b);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

This test out OK, I think.
https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_chiru.php

Man page ref: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Recommend that you try the link before you downvote this or send the author on a wild goose chase writing user code to do what is already built into PHP!

```html
<?php // demo/temp_chiru.php
/**
 * User-Sorting an array
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332372/array-reordering-based-on-key-in-php
 * http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


$arr = Array
( '1' => 'completed'
, '2' => 'completed'
, '3' => 'completed'
, '4' => 'completed'
, '5' => NULL
, 'user_name' => 'ABCD'
)
;

ksort($arr);
var_dump($arr);


$arr = Array
( 1 => 'completed'
, 2 => 'completed'
, 3 => 'completed'
, 4 => 'completed'
, 5 => NULL
, 'user_name' => 'ABCD'
)
;

ksort($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: `ksort()` returns the desired result only by accident. It compares the strings with numbers as numbers, the strings evaluate to `0` and `ksort()` decides they are "smaller" than the numbers. This breaks if `0` is a key in the array. Even more, your code produces different results in PHP 5 and PHP 7. Take a look here: https://3v4l.org/qRBMV

Comment: I tested with zero as an array key and it worked correctly.  In addition I cannot find any man page that suggests the keys are strictly typed, and testing indicates the contrary. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Since my previous example didn't convince you I will provide you a better one: https://3v4l.org/kI2WI

Comment: Do you have a man page reference that shows the changes in ksort() at PHP 7?  I think SORT_REGULAR which seems to be the default is useful and sensible, however, loose typing in array keys can produce some goofy results.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure, the improvements in the sort functions in PHP 7 are [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.other.sort-order).

Comment: Thanks, and I apologize for being off-base on this one; my wife is in the hospital and things like that affect your ability to think clearly.  Probably the best recommendation would have been to design an application that does not need to mix array key types! ;-)